# recordRTC record screen and microphone

Tags: javascript

i'm working on a project where i need to record the user screen with his voice using `RecordRTC`.

Here `RecordRTC` the code thats needed to record screen is:

```
stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
    audio: true,
    video: {
        mediaSource: "screen", // whole screen sharing
    }

})
recorder = new RecordRTC.RecordRTCPromisesHandler(stream, {
    mimeType: 'video/webm', 
});

recorder.startRecording();
```

and, the code thats needed to record microphone  is:

```
stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
   audio: true
})

recorder = new RecordRTC.RecordRTCPromisesHandler(stream, {
    mimeType: 'video/webm', 
});

recorder.startRecording();
```

How do I get media with Microphone Audio and recorded screen video?

link to github repo: [RecordRTC](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC/)